# SSIS Job run in loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

I have an SSIS job which pulls data from one database and pushes into another. Currently the actions are triggered when a record is inserted into a table.

My understanding is using a SQL Server trigger to launch an SSIS Job is not advised. Suggesting to me the preferred route for this use case is to use a recurring schedule.

If I schedule every 10 seconds, will the ETL job launch again if the previous run has not finished? (Is there a better word to describe this behavior in the computing spacing?) If the job relaunches, is there a preferred way to accomplish this behavior?

[image]

Comment: It won't start a new run if a previous scheduled run is still running.

Comment: Why aren't you just using replication for this?

Answer (score 0):

> If I schedule every 10 seconds, will the ETL job launch again if the previous run has  not finished?

No.  The next run time is computed once the job finishes, based on the "Starting at" and the next interval that meets the cycle interval.

While it is running the "Start Job at Step" option on the SQL Server Management Studio interface will be grayed out.

If you try to kick off the job again forcefully using sp_start_job, you'll get a error message saying it's already running.